# Pdf to Tiff file covert in vb.net using PdfSharp.dll

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

i am using Pdfsharp.dll to convert tiff image to pdf file in vb.net, and it is successfull when i run in my machine, when i use it from other machine, which shows the Error like "Raw string contains invalid character with a value > 255.", please any one help me to fix error,
i using the PdfSharp.dll library and the following code

```
    Dim objDoc As PdfDocument
    Dim objPdfPage As PdfPage
    Dim objTiffImg As Image
    Dim objXImg As XImage
    Dim iPageCount As Integer
    Dim objXgr As XGraphics
    Dim sPdfFile As String = Nothing
    Dim objDir As DirectoryInfo
    Dim objFile As FileInfo()
    Dim objFileInfo As FileInfo

    Try
        objTiffImageSpliter = New TiffImageSplitter()
        objDoc = New PdfDocument
        iPageCount = objTiffImageSpliter.GetPageCount(sFileName)

        For iCount As Integer = 0 To iPageCount - 1
            objPdfPage = New PdfPage
            objTiffImg = objTiffImageSpliter.getTiffImage(sFileName, iCount)
            objXImg = XImage.FromGdiPlusImage(objTiffImg)
            'objPdfPage.Height = objXImg.PointWidth
            'objPdfPage.Width = objXImg.PointHeight
            objDoc.Pages.Add(objPdfPage)
            objXgr = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(objDoc.Pages(iCount))
            objXgr.DrawImage(objXImg, 10, 10)
        Next
        sPdfFile = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & "\MY_FaxFile\"

        If System.IO.Directory.Exists(sPdfFile) Then
            objDir = New DirectoryInfo(sPdfFile)
            objFile = objDir.GetFiles()

            For Each objFileInfo In objFile
                objFileInfo.Delete()
            Next

            sPdfFile &= "MyFax.pdf"
        Else
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(sPdfFile)
            sPdfFile &= "MyFax.pdf"
        End If

       objDoc.Save(sPdfFile)   ' This Line shows the Error.
        objDoc.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        sPdfFile = Nothing
    End Try

    Return sPdfFile
```

Comment: Did you try to rule out the possibility of an invalid file name (sPdfFile)?

Comment: Hi Prutswonder thanks for your reply,

Comment: i am not clear of invalid file name, can you please exlain..

Comment: and also the given file(MyFax.pdf) is created sucessfully, but the Error keep comming when executing this line in code 'objDoc.Save(sPdfFile)'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this library, but based on your code and error message, I would guess that your App Data folder contains non-ASCII characters and that the PdfSharp library does not support non-ASCII characters in the filename.

Comment: i am using the path "C:\Documents and Settings\senthilkumar\Application Data\My_FaxFile\MyFax.pdf, it is not containing non_ASCII